# Matplotlib Crashes and Exits on plt.show() with Qt5Agg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt5, pyqt5

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3, Anaconda Python 3.5.5, and matplotlib 2.2.2. Everything has been running great up until today. I tried to generate some graphs and once I typed plt.show(), Python just.. quit. It's quite similar to [issue 4590](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4590).

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.__version__
Out[2]: '2.2.2'

In [3]: matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[3]: 'Qt5Agg'

In [5]: import sys

In [6]: sys.version
Out[6]: '3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 13 2018, 05:02:37) \n[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]'

In [7]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3]);
plt.show();
```

Nothing happens, Python just exits. This is a new problem, and I suspect it has something to do with Qt5, because when I switch backends, I can get it to work.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3]);
plt.show();
```

Everything has been installed via conda-forge. I'm not sure where to go for the error logs to see what's happening. Any advice?

Comment: Cross reference: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10883).

Comment: "So I wound up wiping the HDD and doing a clean install of Linux Mint 18.3, a new install of Anaconda/Python/matplotlib, etc. and everything is back to normal." as seen in the GitHub issue seems to have resolved this. In that sense it's not reproducible and I would vote to close this question.